# Load images from uri

Tags: android, bitmap, uri

I load images from gallery into a gridview which belong to an object (Ejercicio) that i save into a listview. Then when i click on a item of the listview i want to load all of data. How can i load images? I want to save the uri into an ArrayList and then convert those URIs in a Bitmap to show it into the gridview.

Now my code is this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        Uri selectedImageUri = null;
        Uri selectedImage;

        String filePath = null;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECT_FILE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                        if (selectedImage != null) {
                            InputStream imageStream = null;
                            try {
                                imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                                        selectedImage);
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

                            imagenes.add(bmp);
                            imagenesUri.add(selectedImage);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i save the URI as String in a DB and then I transform again this String in a Bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

For loading images from an URI you can use for example imageloader. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

I'd recommend to use a recyclerview and save the loaded images into a simple cache like a map (url, bitmap): `Map<String, Bitmap> images = new HashMap<>()`.

When you want to load the picture in your recyclerview ask the cache first if it's already loaded: `images.containsKey(url)`

Otherwise load the images via imageloader.